# What does having multiple metrics do when training a model?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to decide on metrics to use when fitting my model. I'm curious as to what impact multiple metrics will have?

`metrics={'output_1': 'metric_1', 'output_2': ['metric_2', 'metric_3']})`

vs

`metrics={'output_1': ['metric_1', 'metric_2'], 'output_2': ['metric_3', 'metric_2']})`

Does the order of the metrics matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics will be shown in the logs and on plot to give you an indication of how good your model performs at any particular stage of the training phase. They are not used as optimization functions.

So they won't have any impact on your model (or performance of your model).